# mongoose : How to find by date that start with a given input (like autocomplete : 25/01/2... , 25/01..)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

i have objects stored in db like :

```
[
   {
      "created_at" : ISODate("2020-03-19T07:27:32.158Z"),
   },
   {
      "created_at" : ISODate("2020-03-19T12:10:19.191Z"),
   }
]
```

I would like to find data by **created_at** (that start with) like autocomplete : **25...** , **25/01...** , **25/01/202...**

I have an input date that i can get data in the format : **25/01/2021** : **dd/mm/yyyy**.

the result can be **25** or **25/0** ,

in this case i need to find data that `created_at : start with 25/0`

it's like the method : `$regex: "^" + date` but **with dates**

Comment: convert dates to strings and use the regex

Comment: but how to compare strings with dates in db : `ISODate("2020-03-19T12:10:19.191Z")`

Comment: "convert dates to strings" means translate the date (bson type 9) to a string (bson type 2), e.g. `ISODate("2020-03-19T12:10:19.191Z")` translates to `"19/03/2020"`. Then you can do all filters and comparisons on these strings as needed.

Comment: Just to make it crystal clear you can convert dates to strings on the application level (mongoose schema) and add it as an extra field to your documents. In this case you will need to update all existing documents as a one-off update. Alternatively you can use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/ to convert it runtime. It does not require any changes in the model but is rather expensive calculation on each request. It's up to you which method to choose depending on data access patterns.

Comment: can anyone provide an aggregate with $dateToString exemple as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of the aggregation pipeline that uses [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to convert it runtime. May be quite expensive on large collections as it processes all documents on each request and cannot use an index.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "created_at_str": {
        $dateToString: {
          date: "$created_at",
          format: "%d/%m/%Y" 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "created_at_str": {
        $regex: "^" + date
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "created_at_str": 0
    }
  }
])
```

An example to play with https://mongoplayground.net/p/zXJbsUnli3L